# React delete by id undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to delete an item by ID with React. My backend routes work correctly (node and postgresql). Each time I try to delete an item, it comes back on page refresh. My command line is saying the item I am trying to delete is undefined.

If I put in a specific id (url + id) it works, but not dynamically. Here is an example of an item
0: {item_id: 1, item_name: "Kivik couch", item_price: 799, item_brand: "IKEA", item_category: "furniture", …}

```
   export default class MainContainer extends Component {
  state = {
        items: []
    }
     addItem = (item) => {
        let newItem = this.state.items
        newItem.push(item)
        this.setState({
            items: newItem
        })
    }
//Delete Item
    deleteItem = (item) => {
        let newItem = this.state.items
        newItem.splice(item, 1);
        this.setState({
            items: newItem
        })
    }

   getItems = async () => {

    try {
      const items = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/items/');
      const itemsJson = await items.json();
      this.setState({items: itemsJson});
      return itemsJson
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err, 'error in catch block')
      return err
  }

}


   //delete
    handleDelete = (event,)=>{


    event.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:9000/items/' + this.state.items.item_id, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: { 
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                "item_id": this.state.items.item_id,

            })
              })

    this.deleteItem(event.currentTarget.value)

  }

 componentDidMount(){
    this.getItems().then((data) => console.log(data,'my items'));
  } 



render(){
const itemsList = this.state.items.map((items, index)=>{
return <li className="card" key={index}><Link to={{pathname:`/item/${items.item_id}`, state:items}}>{items.item_id}. {items.item_brand} {items.item_name} ${items.item_price}</Link> <button className="tiny button" value={index} onClick={this.handleDelete}><Icon name="trash" /></button></li>
  })
    return (
         <div className="App">
         <h1>Items</h1>
         <ol className="Grid">{itemsList}</ol>
         <Forms addItem ={this.addItem} />
         </div>
      )
  }
}
```

I am expecting for the item to be deleted on the front end and backend permanently, but instead the item being deleted is undefined and on refresh the item returns to the front end.

Comment: `handleDelete = (event,)=>{...` is invalid syntax

Comment: and `items` is an array, maybe `items[0].item_id`?

Comment: Can you please provide the code of the whole component. It's very difficult to understand what goes wrong without render method.

Comment: If I change to items[0].item_id, the first item gets deleted no matter what item I click delete on

Comment: yes you need to know which item was clicked.

Comment: I have added all of the code

Comment: You should be taking a copy of your state.items array (with `slice`) and then splicing it, or `filter`ing out the element you don't want. All you're doing is assigning a new reference to it which will screw things up when you assign it using `setState`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your handle delete to be like, the following.

```
handleDelete = (event) => {
  // gets the index of the clicked item from value={index}
  const index = event.target.value;
  const item = this.state.items[index];

  event.preventDefault(); 

  if (!item || !item.item_id) {
    alert("No item!");
    return;
  }

  fetch("http://localhost:9000/items/" + item.item_id, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      item_id: item.item_id
    })
  });

  this.deleteItem(event.currentTarget.value);
};
```

Comment: I am getting an error "MainContainer.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'item_id' of undefined" about half of the time when trying to delete. Does this have something to do with index starting from 0 but my id's starting at 1?

Comment: No you need to validate the data before using it.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is, but the same thing is happening. Sometimes the delete works correctly, and some times I get that same error. Usually after I reload the page a few times it begins to work again.

Comment: Could it be an issue with setState in the delete method?

Comment: it's hard to say without seeing the data. please me whats in `items[]`